# unicodePwd issue on new entry to ldap with python

Tags: python, passwords, ldap

I'm trying to insert a new entry in ldap but every time I set unicodePwd it returns:

> {'info': '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003
>   (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to
>   perform'}

I tried this cases:

```
password = unicode('"' + 'inicio@1' + '"', "iso-8859-1")
password = password.encode("utf-16-le")
```

This one:

```
password = str(unicode("inicio@1"))
```

And this:

```
password = 'inicio@1'
password = ''.join(('"', password, '"')).encode('utf-16').lstrip('\377\376')
```

I'm using ldap on port 389.
Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx.

It says that is necessary to use TLS to edit unicodePwd attribute. So I need to use ldaps over 636 port.